# After update to .NET 7, I get an error : System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, migration, .net-7.0

I created a project with ASP.NET Core 6 and developed it over time.
Now I updated this project to .NET 7.

So far there have been no problems. I had no errors at runtime. The program works correctly.

After the update, when I run the `add--migration` command, I encounter an error whose origin is unknown.

I updated all nuget packages of the program.

`Add-Migration -name test2 Build started... Build succeeded.`

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.AddSeedData(IEntityType entityType, Dictionary`2 identityMaps, EntityState initialState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.TrackData(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDataOperations(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Description
```

I used nlog to debug and I got this error.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostAbortedException: The host was aborted.     at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.ThrowHostAborted()     at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 value)     at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)     at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.ResolveHost(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener)     at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()     at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in H:\Project\Rafa\erp\WebUI\Program.cs:line 61
```

I changed nullable values with ?
And I also put nullables context in the disable mode in the build propetries
I also used Debugger.Launch, but i got an error on
var app = builder.Build();
I encountered an exception

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostAbortedException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The host was aborted.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.ThrowHostAborted()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 value)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.ResolveHost(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in H:\Project\Rafa\erp\WebUI\Program.cs:line 61

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

    [External Code]
    Program.<Main>$(string[]) in Program.cs
```

Comment: Try locating `HasData` calls in your model configuration code. The original error seems to be related to such method (aka model data seeding) calls, unfortunately cannot be said for which entity, so you might try commenting them out one by one until the error disappears.

Comment: In addition to Ivan's note - especially pay attention to entities in `HasData` that come from external libraries.

Comment: I did not add any new properties.
I also did not use hasdata.

In fact, migration is a stored procedure for creating a function.
There is a version of the same project with .net 6 and it performs the migration without any problems.

The client wants to upgrade to .net 7.

Comment: I reverted all NuGet packages from 7.0.2 to 6.0.5.
In this case, add-migration works correctly

Comment: You are not reading carefully the comments. It doesn't matter what the new migration is doing and whether the code works in pre EFC 7. Look at ALL your code for `HasData` calls. See, the stack trace "**at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.AddSeedData(IEntityType entityType, Dictionary'2 identityMaps, EntityState initialState)**" for me is clear indication that you have `HasData` somewhere. EF Core team has habits of fixing "incorrect behaviors" of their previous versions, and breaking user code. In this case it could be unique in-memory index, etc.

Comment: Could you please share more details of your DbContext class based on this `"I changed nullable values with ? And I also put nullables context in the disable mode"`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts

Comment: thanks mr ivan-stoev ,I found that error,
An attribute in one of the classes was defined as a non-nullable string. This value was not set at the time of creation by hasdata. I set the default value for it and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had a `HasData` statement for Entity type `A` but I was creating a different type `B`. I'm surprised this even compiled. It took me a while to find.

```cs
builder.Entity<A>().HasData(new B { ... });
```